# DataFrame merging with replacing value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two Dataframe:

```
    A    B    C
0   a-1  b-1  c-1
1   a-2  b-2  NaN
2   a-3  b-3  NaN
3   a-4  b-4  c-4
```

SECOND:

```
    C
1   c-2
2   c-3
```

How can I update the first dataframe by value from the second based on the same index?
So I expect to see the following:

```
    A    B    C
0   a-1  b-1  c-1
1   a-2  b-2  c-2  ## as id 1 from the second df has c as c-2
2   a-3  b-3  c-3  ## as id 2 from the second df has c as c-3
3   a-4  b-4  c-4
```

Thanks everyone for helping

Answer (score 1):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
df1 = df1.combine_first(df2)
print(df1)

# Output
     A    B    C
0  a-1  b-1  c-1
1  a-2  b-2  c-2
2  a-3  b-3  c-3
3  a-4  b-4  c-4
```

or `fillna`:

```
df1 = df1.fillna(df2)
print(df1)

# Output
     A    B    C
0  a-1  b-1  c-1
1  a-2  b-2  c-2
2  a-3  b-3  c-3
3  a-4  b-4  c-4
```